# How to delete multiple non-adjacent columns in Excel at the same time?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

When I select multiple (non-adjacent) columns and try to delete them in one move, Excel grays out the options for deleting columns. The column deletion options are only available when I select adjacent columns.  Why is this the case, and is there a way to delete multiple non-adjacent columns at the same time?

[image: Grayed-out deletion options]

Comment: A Macro can easily do it,,, soon I'll post one.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Micro$soft has decided that non-contiguous columns, with at least one of them intersecting a Table, can't be deleted simultaneously. As for the why, you'll have to ask *them*. (Maybe because it's "too hard" as Tables were a late added-in feature.)

You *can* otherwise delete multiple non-contiguous columns simultaneously.

If it's something that you wish to do regularly with Tables, it *is* possible to write some VBA, and map it to a keyboard shortcut (even to the <kbd>Del</kbd> key) or add it to the ribbon, to do so. The code would cycle through the columns and delete them one by one.

Answer (score -1):

As you have created **[Excel table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)**, I believe it is not possible. You have to delete non-adjacent columns one by one.

[(Reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940979/cannot-delete-a-column-that-contains-multiple-tables)

Answer (score -1):

*I would like to suggest you simple Macro, to delete multiple non-adjacent columns in one stroke.*

```
Public Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant

    arr = Split("2-4-6", "-") 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Sheet1
        For i = UBound(arr) + 1 To LBound(arr) + 1 Step -1
            .Cells(Val(arr(i - 1))).EntireColumn.Delete
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- You can replace values in Split("2-4-6",,) with required Column
  numbers like Split("1-3-5").
- *Column's order must be Ascending*.
- **With Sheet1**, is also editable.